# aegir migration did not update database

Tags: migrations, aegir

I am working with aegir 3 (hostmaster-7.x-3.130). After migration of Drupal website from an older platform (drupal version 8.3.7) to a newer version (drupal 8.5.0). Website is sucessfully verified after migration (all drupal modules are updatet as expected). No Error or Warning. Task queue turns green.

However, I figure out that database (as well as drupal entity) updates did not run during the migration, so I have to run "drush updb" and "drush entup" manuelly after the aegir migration.

How can I get aegir-migration automatically updating the database (entity) etc.?

Many thanks and regards

Tom

Answer (score 0):

These operations should be running automatically so there's nothing for you to do; this is clearly a bug.  Let's continue the discussion in the bug report at [Aegir migration did not update database](https://www.drupal.org/project/hostmaster/issues/2954896).  Hopefully we can track down the problem over there.